# Swift pagination with API

Tags: json, swift, pagination, uikit

From api response I have page and nextPage as String. There are total of 2 pages and page number is appended at the end of the request.

Sample request url is
`.../listing/{page}`. In my case since there are 2 pages request urls are `(.../listing/1)` and `(.../listing/2)`. For first request `(.../listing/1)` I get 20 items and nextPage = 2 and for second request which is `(.../listing/2)` I get another array of items.

For second request there is no nextPage parameter, and I would like to send request to the API till there is no nextPage parameter with using pagination.

How can I build this logic?

Comment: Please add the code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: you have to maintain two variables ```currentPage``` and ```nextPage```. If nextPage is greater than the current page you request for the next page.